# Cannot install git through homebrew on yosemite

Tags: git, homebrew, homebrew-cask

Having problems installing git with homebrew. Tried every past solution available. I do have write permissions on /usr/local. I can do brew update and brew doctor with no issues, but it says I have git-git (whatever that is) already installed. I have oh-my-zsh shell. i have xcode with git and atom installed if that may be relevant.

```
Last login: Tue Feb 24 09:56:18 on console
    You have new mail.

# user at mymac in ~ [9:57:48]
$ brew install git
Error: git-git already installed
To install this version, first `brew unlink git'

# user at mymac in ~ [9:57:54]
$ brew unlink git
Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/git

# user at mymac in ~ [9:58:04]
$ brew update
Updated Homebrew from b33e8a75 to cf5325ac.
==> New Formulae
deisctl         gcovr       pdf-redact-tools
==> Updated Formulae
activemq    couchdb-lucene  hamsterdb   libgadu     redpen
avian       datomic     httpie      libmpdclient    unittest
berkeley-db gtk-gnutella    ice     mysql
cctools     h2o     ipsumdump   mysql-cluster

# user at mymac in ~ [10:01:04]
$ brew doctor
Your system is ready to brew.

# user at mymac in ~ [10:01:25]
$ brew install git
Error: git-git already installed
To install this version, first `brew unlink git'

# user at mymac in ~ [10:01:30]
$ brew unlink git
Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/git

# user at mymac in ~ [10:01:35]
$ brew link git
Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/git

# user at mymac in ~ [10:01:44]
$ git --version
zsh: command not found: git

# user at mymac in ~ [10:02:01]
$ brew --version
0.9.5

# user at mymac in ~ [10:06:17]
$ git-git --version
zsh: command not found: git-git

# user at mymac in ~ [10:11:32]
$ which git-git
git-git not found
```

**Update:** I tried changing shell back to bash. Same issue.

```
mymac:~ user$ git --version 
-bash: git: command not found 
mymac:~ user$ brew install git 
Error: git-git already installed To install this version, first `brew    unlink git' 
mymac:~ user$ –
```

Forgot to mention i'm using yosemite 10.10.2

Comment: Doesn't homebrew use Git internally? How is it possible that homebrew works (`brew update`), but running `git --version` says that `git` is not on your path? Can you try to run `brew install git` from Bash instead of zsh?

Comment: It does. I actually tried uninstalling homebrew and was surprised to see it re-installed successfully. I will try bash.

Comment: mymac:~ user$ git --version
-bash: git: command not found
mymac:~ user$ brew install git
Error: git-git already installed
To install this version, first `brew unlink git'
mymac:~ user$

Comment: Something is weird with your environment. The second part of the `git-git` is supposed to be the version number in case a formula is already installed (see https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/28d1b4b6f77ab77107d2a83c81945a07316da2db/Library/Homebrew/cmd/install.rb#L74). If I run `brew install git` locally, it shows: `Warning: git-2.3.0 already installed`.

Comment: You might want to open an issue over at the Homebrew project on GitHub: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues

Comment: What's in /usr/local/Cellar/git? Try `rm -rf /usr/local/Cellar/git`.

Answer (score 1):

From the command line do

```
where git
```

you may get two locations

```
/usr/bin/git
/usr/local/bin/git
```

then do

```
 /usr/bin/git --version
```

you should get

```
git version 2.5.4 (Apple Git-61)
```

this is the installed version that comes with Mac OS

then check the version on this path

```
/usr/local/bin/git --version
git version 2.7.1
```

this is the current version

then check your path

```
echo $PATH
```

and ensure that '/usr/local/bin/' is early in your path otherwise it will not execute the git command, if not edit your path.